# Assign string value to a character if character placed in string (array)

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var text = [];

text[0] = 'xyй';

text[0][0] = 'c';

alert(text[0][0]); // = 'xyй'
```

I think that it is necessary to convert a string into an array? Is this true?

Comment: I'm not understanding the question what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Try this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: Strings are [**immutable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutability).

Comment: Pretty sure that output should be `'x'`

Comment: LMAO `:D` Amazing example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/ENeZOJe/1/edit)**

```
var text = [];
text[0] = 'xyй';
//break each string at each character into array
text[0] = text[0].split('');
//replace array item
text[0][0] = 'c';
//rejoin array into string
text[0] = text[0].join('');
console.log(text[0]);

var text = [];
text[0] = 'xyй';
//replace first character (character 0) with 'c'
text[0] = text[0].replace(text[0].charAt(0), 'c');
console.log(text[0]);
```